# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve 'RedisCache' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis

In my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project, I am implementing Redis for Memory Cache using this package `StackExchange.Redis` version 2.6.111.

I have this code:

`appsettings.json`:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "RedisUrl": "127.0.0.1:1022"
  },
```

Then I have this injection:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Hrm.API.Extensions
{
    public static class RedisCacheExtension
    {
        public static void AddRedisCacheInjection(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            // Configure Redis Cache
            services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(config.GetConnectionString("RedisUrl")));
            services.AddSingleton<IDistributedCache>(x => new RedisCache(x.GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>(), "SampleInstance"));

            // Configure MemoryCache
            services.AddMemoryCache();
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this errors:

> CS1729 'RedisCache' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

and `RedisCache` is highlighted.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The [only public constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d47e49e9c1e173ac90821f7e89cc38e710274241/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/RedisCache.cs#LL70C58-L70C58) seems to be `public RedisCache(IOptions<RedisCacheOptions> optionsAccessor)`. You don't need to create your own `ConnectionMultiplexer`